# EJS Spread Attributes

Tags: express, ejs

How would I implement destruction a object to a elements attributes in EJS?

In JSX I would do:

```html
<div {...props}> </div>
```

How would I implementate this with EJS?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<%
    function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
        return unsafe
            .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
            .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
            .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
            .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
            .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
    }
    function spread(object) {
        return Object.entries(t).reduce((a, [k, v]) => `${a} ${k}="${escapeHtml(v)}"`, "");
    }
%>
```

Usage

```html
<div <%- spread(props) %>> </div>
```